# Creating file using windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a windows service which creates a file on local drive (C:\Testing folder).

I have installed this service. I am starting this service from web application hosted in IIS.

If i hardcode this path in service code, the service works fine but if I pass the path through web application to the web service, Events log showing an excepetion

> Service cannot be started. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Testing' is denied.

I have admin access on my machine and I am starting the service with the same account. How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: You have to add Write permissions to your Testing folder for the `LOCAL SERVICE` user account (or whatever user account your service runs under).

Comment: Or alternatively use a folder that is usually already configured fro everyone to use e.g. Temp

Comment: How do you communicate between the web application and the windows service? Are you certain that it is the service that is accessing the path, and not the web app using the service's code?

Comment: @SpikeX: I gave full permission to LOCAL SERVICE account to testing folder. I also gave full permission to windows login account. Still geting the same exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake. I need to provide file name as well with the path. Its working fine now. Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 15):

As SpikeX said, your service needs to have read-write access to the folder c:\Testing

Right-click on the folder and change security permissions. "Local Service" for Local System account:

[image]

or if your service runs under a specific account (e.g. your own Windows admin account), give that account write permissions to the folder.

The service security tab in Services.msc:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to verify which account is trying to write to C:\Testing.  It could be that an account other than the one you expect is trying to create the file.

Answer (score -1):

When you map a drive on your local system then in such a case you are suppose to give rights to network service on shared folder you are accessing through windows service.